# shell: replacing string in a file using sed

Tags: linux, shell, replace

I am writing a script to replace a string in a file in linux.

this is my code:

```
echo "Enter file name? "
read FILE1
echo "You have entered, $FILE1"

echo "String to be replaced "
read STR1
echo "You have entered, $STR1"

echo "Replace by "
read STR2
echo "You have entered, $STR2"

sed -i 's/$STR1/$STR2/g' /misc/home3/abc/$FILE1

echo "DONE !!"
```

The string is not getting replace in the file.
what could be wrong with it??

Thanks :)

Comment: Variables aren't parsed in single quotes; use double quotes; ie. `"s/$str1/$str2/g"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `'` for the sed-string but `"` like this:

```
sed -i "s/$STR1/$STR2/g" /misc/home3/abc/$FILE1
```

Double quotes allow the shell to do variable expansion inside of the quoted text. Single tick `'` prevents this.